# Use a variable containing a string of dates in an update statement in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, varchar

I am wanting to have a script which updates a table of days, setting the bankHoliday flag to true if it exists in a given list.

This list is something a user would update every year or two:

```sql
DECLARE @dateList VARCHAR(MAX) = '2024-01-01, 2024-03-29, 2024-04-01, 2024-05-06, 2024-05-27,
    2024-08-26, 2024-12-25, 2024-12-26, 2025-01-01,
    2025-04-18, 2025-04-21, 2025-05-05, 2025-05-26,
    2025-08-25, 2025-12-25, 2025-12-26';
```

The update happens at the bottom of a long script, so though I can tell the user at the top something like "--make sure to go to ~line 300 and update the list of bank holidays", I would prefer to have this list at the top in a variable and then refer to it down in the update.

The first problem I have is for it to be easily visible, it can be on multiple lines and have spaces, like the above example. So I have this bit of code following it to strip out all the wrong characters:

```sql
-- Replace the dashes with single quotes
SET @dateList = REPLACE(@dateList, ',', ''',''');

-- Replace multiple spaces and new lines with a single space
SET @dateList = REPLACE(REPLACE(@dateList, CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), ' '), ' ', '');

-- Add single quotes at the beginning and end
SET @dateList = '''' + @dateList + '''';
```

Doing `select @dateList` at this point returns this:
'2024-01-01','2024-03-29','2024-04-01','2024-05-06','2024-05-27','2024-08-26','2024-12-25','2024-12-26','2025-01-01','2025-04-18','2025-04-21','2025-05-05','2025-05-26','2025-08-25','2025-12-25','2025-12-26'

So now, down at the bottom of the script, i want to use @dateList in my update:

I tried the following, but each time get the same error:
**Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.**

```sql
UPDATE days
SET    days.PublicHoliday = 1
WHERE  days.Date IN
(
  SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@dateList, ',')
);
```

```sql
UPDATE days
SET    days.PublicHoliday = 1
WHERE  days.Date IN
(
  @dateList
);
```

```sql
UPDATE days
SET    days.PublicHoliday = 1
WHERE  days.Date IN
(
  SELECT CONVERT(datetime, value) FROM STRING_SPLIT(@dateList, ',')
);
```

Again, if i put the result of @dateList directly into the update, it works fine:

```sql
UPDATE days
SET    days.PublicHoliday = 1
WHERE  days.Date IN
(
  '2024-01-01','2024-03-29','2024-04-01','2024-05-06','2024-05-27','2024-08-26','2024-12-25','2024-12-26','2025-01-01','2025-04-18','2025-04-21','2025-05-05','2025-05-26','2025-08-25','2025-12-25','2025-12-26'
);
```

but i want to avoid this if possible as it requires trusting the user to go to the foot of the script.

Comment: `IN (@dateList)` doesn't do what you think it does; it would be equivalent to `= @dateList` You can't just dump a *scalar* variable into an `IN` and expect SQL Server to treat is like a tuple. Use a table type variable/parameter or temporary table.

Comment: Also `yyyy-MM-dd` is **not** unambigious with the `datetime` datatype. What happens with your `STRING_SPLIT` solution if you use an unambiguous format (`yyyyMMdd`)?

Comment: That's just a string, not dates. Splitting on `,` means that all values except one will have a leading space character, eg `' 2023-01-01'` instead of `'2023-01-01'`. The safe option is to use a table-valued parameter of `date` values. Another option is to use a JSON array with a `WITH` clause that defines the values as dates, eg `select MyDate from openjson('["2023-12-31","2022-02-02"]') with (MyDate date '$')`

Comment: The IN(@datleList) was just me clutching for straws after the previous attempts failed, but thought i'd put it on here to show everything i tried. I also tried the yyyyMMdd example and got the same error, but I wasn't aware of the ambiguity, so thanks for explaining that

Comment: The earlier formatting removed all the spaces (after a bit of trial and error), so i was ending up with what I thought was the right string of 'date,date,date' but was still getting the conversion error.

Comment: `I also tried the yyyyMMdd example and got the same error`. No repro. `select cast('20231231' as datetime)` no matter what `DATEFORMAT` I set. On the other hand, `set dateformat dmy;` will cause `select cast('2023-12-31' as datetime)`. On the other hand, `select cast('2023-12-31' as date)` isn't affected at all. Instead of comparing a date field to a string, cast the `value` to a date with `SELECT CAST(value as date)...`

Comment: Newlines. Your string contains newlines that become part of the date string and cause it to fail.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, a `varchar` variable is just a string of data, it doesn't automatically become a list.

Instead of messing around with splitting strings and conversion, **just use a table variable or a Table Valued Parameter.** Also use an unambiguous date format such as `yyyyMMdd` or `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`

```sql
DECLARE @dateList AS TABLE (value date PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT @dateList (value) VALUES
('20240101'),
('20240329'),
('20240401'),
('20240506'),
('20240527'),
('20240826'),
('20241225'),
('20241226'),
('20250101'),
('20250418'),
('20250421'),
('20250505'),
('20250526'),
('20250825'),
('20251225'),
('20251226');
```

And then

```sql
UPDATE days
SET    PublicHoliday = 1
WHERE  days.Date IN
(
    SELECT value FROM @dateList
);
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining this - I got a bit fixated on trying to manipulate the string and mould it into the right shape that I forgot about doing it this way, which is much simpler and does the job quickly and efficiently. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The other answer shows how to safely and properly pass a list of dates. The reason the current attempt fails is that the string contains *newlines*, not just commas and whitespace.

This fails with a conversion error:

```
select cast(value as date)
from STRING_SPLIT(@dateList,',')
```

To investigate this, `TRY_CAST` can be used to return `NULL` for invalid dates. The result of :

```
select try_cast(value as date)
from STRING_SPLIT(@dateList,',')
```

is

```
2024-01-01
2024-03-29
2024-04-01
2024-05-06
2024-05-27
NULL
2024-12-25
2024-12-26
2025-01-01
NULL
2025-04-21
2025-05-05
2025-05-26
NULL
2025-12-25
2025-12-26
```

If a TVP can't be used, a safe-ish alternative is to use a JSON array *string* and parse it with `OPENJSON`. The following string gets parsed without problems:

```
DECLARE @dateList VARCHAR(MAX) = '["2024-01-01", "2024-03-29", "2024-04-01", "2024-05-06", "2024-05-27",
    "2024-08-26", "2024-12-25", "2024-12-26", "2025-01-01",
    "2025-04-18", "2025-04-21", "2025-05-05", "2025-05-26",
    "2025-08-25", "2025-12-25", "2025-12-26"]';

select MyDate
from OPENJSON(@dateList) with (MyDate date '$')
```

This produces

```
MyDate
----------
2024-01-01
2024-03-29
2024-04-01
2024-05-06
2024-05-27
2024-08-26
2024-12-25
2024-12-26
2025-01-01
2025-04-18
2025-04-21
2025-05-05
2025-05-26
2025-08-25
2025-12-25
2025-12-26
```

That's still not as good, and takes more actual space than a TVP.

Answer (score -1):

Create a table of values like this. Update with this table.

```
DECLARE @dateList VARCHAR(MAX) = '2024-01-01, 2024-03-29, 2024-04-01, 2024-05-06, 2024-05-27, 2024-08-26, 2024-12-25, 2024-12-26, 2025-01-01, 2025-04-18, 2025-04-21, 2025-05-05, 2025-05-26, 2025-08-25, 2025-12-25, 2025-12-26';

DECLARE @dates TABLE (dt DATE)
INSERT INTO @dates 
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(LEFT(dt,4), SUBSTRING(dt, 6,2), SUBSTRING(dt, 9,2)) as date
FROM
(SELECT TRIM(value) as dt FROM string_split(@dateList, ',')) val

SELECT * FROM @dates
```